# Delete a photo in whatsapp but not the message that contains it

Tags: iphone, ios

Because I turned off Media Auto-Download in Storage and Data in WhatsApp's settings, when photos arrive they are blurry and I can choose to download them.

[image]

*image 1*

After downloading them, I can see the photos in original resolution.

[image]

*image 2*

How can I delete my local copies, and return the chat to its previous state (image 1)?

Deleting the image from the chat, and deleting the image from WhatsApp's Settings > Storage and Data > Manage Storage, deletes the entire message for me and it looks like this afterwards:

[image]

*image 3*

But I want to go from image 2 to image 1, I don't want to lose the:

- text attached to the images
- the image previews
- ability to download the images again

It should be as if I hadn't tapped download yet.